# Identifying if 2 HTML pages are similar

Tags: .net, diff, similarity, fuzzy

I'm trying to identify differences between a base case and supplied case. Looking for a library to tell me similarity in percentage or something like that.

For Example:

I've 10 different HTML pages. 
* All of them are 404 responses with only one 2 lines of random code (such as time or quote of the day).

Now when I supply a new 404 page I want a result back such as "%80" similar,however if I supply another page totally different or same website but quite different content I should get something lile "%20 similar".

Basically what I want to do is, when I've got a new response I want to identify if the new response is similar to these 10 pages which I supplied before.

I'm trying to solve this in .NET, A library or an algorithm recommendation would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a diff tool you could use a copy/paste detector (cpd).  Then you can configure a threshold of how alike you want files to be.

As an aside, I have used these in the past to track down cheaters in school.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a string based solution you can give a shot using k-grams (you compute all the string of length k of consecutive chars for both files, then you perform a Jaccard distance on the resulting sets). It is a standard way to perform approximate queries in DB world.

If you are interested more in hierarchical information embedded into the html file (e.g. you were talking about an unmutable section) you can convert it into an xhtml (for java you have http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/, I'm not into .net but I think there are several alternatives for that env too), seeing the file generated as an ordered labelled tree you can use pq-grams (http://www.inf.unibz.it/~augsten/publ/tods10/ for paper and java code) to evaluate structural similarity (pq-grams are a tree generalization of string k-grams).

At this point if you want you can perform an hash-based comparison on the leaf containing text or using k-grams for this leaves and structural pq-gram based similarity for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to compute the Levenshtein distance of the markup.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_distance

Answer (score 0):

for your task it would be enough to run a command line diff utility and analyze the results.

Alternatively you need to implement an [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm but to me it would be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> for your task it would be enough to
>   run a command line diff utility and
>   analyze the results.

This is not a one time job really, I need a solution integrated into an application.

And diff has it's own problems in here, because I can not tell diff to process 5 pages and ignore the bits those constantly changing.

These parts can be big, it can 2kb of standard text keep changing. And I think from diff point of view it's a big change however from my point of view it's just a change of one section (which is known to be changed in all other 9 files therefore should be ignored totally).

Maybe a diff library can do that but I'm not aware of such a library.

Answer (score 0):

basic algorithm i would use:

parse the text content of pages on both sides, the old and the new. as you parse keep track on how many bytes have processed to be used later on to determine how many % has changed. Now that you have complete story on each side, build up anchor points of sameness. For every achor point of sameness that you've got, try to expand that forward and backward. Identify any gaps between your sameness achor points as a difference. Loop through every difference gap that you've identified and sum up their byte counts. calculate your percentage of diff by using the total ammount difference byte count and the total byte of the story (the one you calculated earlier).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqgram, an implementation of PQ-Gram tree edit distance approximation to specifically solve this problem, but you'll need to run Node.js if you don't want to port to C#.  The port should be pretty easy though... the algorithm isn't all that complex.  Beauty in simplicity.

https://github.com/hoonto/jqgram

In the example is a DOM vs cheerio example which shows how to deal with children and labels so as to generate the approximate tree edit distance.  It gives you a number between zero and one as a result, and so that is your percentage equality.  But note that a value of zero doesn't necessarily indicate identical trees, it only means they are very similar.  You could do DOM vs DOM comparison or Cheerio vs Cheerio easily enough too - or use the HTML parse that Cheerio uses instead of worrying about using the entire library (Cheerio out of the box is a rather fast server-side jQuery- and DOM-like implementation).

So obviously this solution is Node.js and browser javascript specific, but I think those challenges might be easier than porting to C#/.NET.

```
// This could probably be optimized significantly, but is a real-world
// example of how to use tree edit distance in the browser.

// For cheerio, you'll have to browserify, 
// which requires some fiddling around
// due to cheerio's dynamically generated 
// require's (good grief) that browserify 
// does not see due to the static nature 
// of its code analysis (dynamic off-line
// analysis is hard, but doable).
//
// Ultimately, the goal is to end up with 
// something like this in the browser:

var cheerio = require('./lib/cheerio'); 

// The easy part, jqgram:
var jq = require("../jqgram").jqgram;

// Make a cheerio DOM:
var html = '<body><div id="a"><div class="c d"><span>Irrelevent text</span></div></div></body>';

var cheeriodom = cheerio.load(html, {
    ignoreWhitespace: false,
    lowerCaseTags: true
});

// For ease, lets assume you have jQuery laoded:
var realdom = $('body');

// The lfn and cfn functions allow you to specify
// how labels and children should be defined:
jq.distance({
    root: cheeriodom,
    lfn: function(node){ 
        // We don't have to lowercase this because we already
        // asked cheerio to do that for us above (lowerCaseTags).
        return node.name; 
    },
    cfn: function(node){ 
        // Cheerio maintains attributes in the attribs array:
        // We're going to put id's and classes in as children 
        // of nodes in our cheerio tree
        var retarr = []; 
        if(!! node.attribs && !! node.attribs.class){
            retarr = retarr.concat(node.attribs.class.split(' '));
        }
        if(!! node.attribs && !! node.attribs.id){
            retarr.push(node.attribs.id);
        }
        retarr = retarr.concat(node.children);
        return  retarr;
    }
},{
    root: realdom,
    lfn: function(node){ 
        return node.nodeName.toLowerCase(); 
    },
    cfn: function(node){ 
        var retarr = [];
        if(!! node.attributes && !! node.attributes.class && !! node.attributes.class.nodeValue){
            retarr = retarr.concat(node.attributes.class.nodeValue.split(' '));
        }
        if(!! node.attributes && !! node.attributes.id && !! node.attributes.id.nodeValue) {
            retarr.push(node.attributes.id.nodeValue);
        }
        for(var i=0; i<node.children.length; ++i){
            retarr.push(node.children[i]);
        }
        return retarr;
    }
},{ p:2, q:3, depth:10 },
function(result) {
    console.log(result.distance);
});
```